# $Q_p(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is a $p$-th root of $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I'm not looking for a full solution, only a hint please!

Let $\zeta$ be a $p$-th root of unity in an algebraic closure of $Q_p$. Show that $Q_p(\zeta) = Q_p ((-p)^{\frac{1}{p-1}})$.

Following a hint in the exercise, I write $p = (1- \zeta)^{p-1} \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon \in Q_p(\zeta)$ and try to show that $-\varepsilon$ is $p-1$th potence in $Q_p(\zeta)$. For this it would be sufficient to see that

a) $-\varepsilon \in R'$ (the valuation Ring of $Q_p(\zeta)$)

b) $-\varepsilon \equiv 1 \mod p$

For a) I can simply compute the absolute value of $(1- \zeta)^{p-1}$ and deduce that $|\varepsilon|=1$. But how can I see that $\varepsilon \equiv -1 \mod p$ and not some other unit?

I've tried some arithmetic tricks with $p = (1- \zeta)^{p-1} \varepsilon$ to see that $\varepsilon^2 \equiv -\varepsilon \mod p$, but it was fruitless.

Comment: What is $Q_p$? The $p$-adic field?

Comment: The $p$-adic field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For b) you can use Wilson's theorem, and the finite geometric series, i.e.,
$$
\epsilon=\frac{p}{(1-\zeta)^{p-1}}=\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1-\zeta^i}{1-\zeta}=\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}\zeta^j
\equiv (p-1)!\equiv -1 \mod (1-\zeta)
$$

Comment: The maximal ideal in $R'$ is actually generated by $(1-\zeta)$? Do I see this right? (it makes kind of sense as $Nm(p)=Nm(1-\zeta)^n$)
Sorry for the probably stupid question, but in our lecture we had so far just worked with number fields, then abstractly introduced absolute values on fields and their behavior under extensions. So I've never actually seen $Q_p$ in 'wild nature', but from what I've seen in number fields (i.e. $Q(\zeta)$), it makes sense to me that $(p) = (1-\zeta)^{p-1}$.

Comment: @Louis: yes, you are right. $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta)\supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ is totally ramified of degree $e=p-1$, and $(p)=(1-\zeta)^e$.